# query two parameters mongodb

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongodb-query

Has anybody an idea, how I can modify this code in a way so that I can search after either only a title or only a rating or both? I have already tried serveral ways including using the $and operator, however I had no success

```
  static async getMovies({
    filters = null,
    page = 0,
    moviesPerPage = 20,
  } = {}) {
    let query = {}
    if (filters) {
      if ("title" in filters) {
        console.log(filters["title"]);
        query.title = { $regex: filters["title"], $options: "i" };
      }  if ("rated" in filters) {
        query.rated = { $eq: filters["rated"] };
      }
    }

    let cursor
    try {
      cursor = await movies.find(query)
        .limit(moviesPerPage)
        .skip(moviesPerPage * page);
      const moviesList = await cursor.toArray();

      for (let i = 0; i < moviesList.length; i++) {
        const movie = moviesList[i];
        const movieReviews = await reviews
          .find({ movie_id: movie._id })
          .toArray();
        movie.review = movieReviews;
      }

      const totalNumMovies = await movies.countDocuments(query);
      return { moviesList, totalNumMovies };
    } catch (e) {
      console.error(`Unable to issue find command, ${e}`);
      return { moviesList: ["error"], totalNumMovies: 0 };
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to search with either name or rating and both then you can simply use the below query. you don't need to use the $eq operator with a rated's filter. mongoose find function matches the direct value without using the $eq operator.

```
if (filters?.title) {
  query.title = { $regex: `^${filters.title.replace(/[-[\]{}()*+?.,\\/^$|#\s]/g, "\\$&")}`, $options: "i" }
}  
if (filters?.rated) {
  query.rated = filters.rated
}
console.log(query)
```